# How to get filters above the product grid Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, product-grid

How can i get the filters above the product grid like in the screenshot?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't have it on the product grid as far as I know because this grid is rendered using a `ui_component`. These kind of filters are there when we create a grid using blocks. You need to remove this grid in your `custom module` and follow the link- https://jutesenthil.wordpress.com/2016/04/11/how-to-create-admin-grid-in-magento2-part5/ to make this kind of grid.